# How do I limit the height of a rotated text cell of a latex table?

Tags: tables, rotating

I've created a table whose columns - except for the first one - only contain a single minus or plus sign, so can be very narrow.

The titles of these columns, however, are quite long. I couldn't quite fit them in in a nice way, so decided to rotate them 90 degrees.

Now it looks much better, but I have a new problem - I can't find a way to introduce line breaks in the titles, which makes them stretch the table height way beyond necessary:

[image: compiled table]

Is there a way to limit the height, or manually introduce line breaks into the titles?

Code for the table above:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!tbh]
\begin{tabular}{|l|>{\centering}p{1.5cm}|>{\centering}p{1.5cm}|>{\centering}p{1.5cm}|>{\centering}p{1.5cm}|>{\centering}p{1.5cm}|}
\hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Strategy}} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Requirement}}\tabularnewline
\cline{2-6} \cline{3-6} \cline{4-6} \cline{5-6} \cline{6-6} 
 & \begin{turn}{90}
First requirement
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
Second requirement
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
And so on
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
And so forth
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
And so fifth
\end{turn}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
\emph{Bla} & + & -- & -- & -- & +\tabularnewline
\hline 
\emph{Bla bla} & -- & -- & + & -- & +\tabularnewline
\hline 
\emph{Bla bla bla} & -- & + & + & -- & --\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\caption{\textbf{This is a table.} It shows things.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!tbh]
\begin{tabular}{|l|>{\centering}p{1.5cm}|>{\centering}p{1.5cm}|>{\centering}p{1.5cm}|>{\centering}p{1.5cm}|>{\centering}p{1.5cm}|}
\hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Strategy}} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Requirement}}\tabularnewline
\cline{2-6} \cline{3-6} \cline{4-6} \cline{5-6} \cline{6-6} 
 & \begin{turn}{90}
{\tabular{@{}l@{}}First\\ requirement\endtabular} 
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
{\tabular{@{}l@{}}Second\\ requirement\endtabular}
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
And so on
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
And so forth
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
And so fifth
\end{turn}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
\emph{Bla} & + & -- & -- & -- & +\tabularnewline
\hline 
\emph{Bla bla} & -- & -- & + & -- & +\tabularnewline
\hline 
\emph{Bla bla bla} & -- & + & + & -- & --\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\caption{\textbf{This is a table.} It shows things.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**OR**

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs}

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!tbh]
\begin{tabular}{l>{\centering}p{1cm}>{\centering}p{1cm}>{\centering}p{1cm}>{\centering}p{1cm}>{\centering}p{1cm}}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Strategy}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Requirement}}\tabularnewline
\cline{2-6} \cline{3-6} \cline{4-6} \cline{5-6} \cline{6-6} 
 & \begin{turn}{90}
{\tabular{@{}l@{}}First\\ requirement\endtabular} 
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
{\tabular{@{}l@{}}Second\\ requirement\endtabular}
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
And so on
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
And so forth
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
And so fifth
\end{turn}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
\emph{Bla} & + & -- & -- & -- & +\tabularnewline
\hline 
\emph{Bla bla} & -- & -- & + & -- & +\tabularnewline
\hline 
\emph{Bla bla bla} & -- & + & + & -- & --\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{\textbf{This is a table.} It shows things.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Some suggestions:

- If you wish to limit the width of a paragraph of text -- yes, in TeX's eyes the objects "First requirement", "Second requirement", etc are paragraphs -- and preserve automatic line breaking, you may stick the paragraphs into `\parbox` statements.
- `\parbox` takes two arguments: (i) the overall width -- set to `\widthof{And so forth\ }` in the example below -- and (ii) the text. I chose this particular width in order to limit the number of header cells that needed line breaking to a manageable small number. Instead of calculating the width "on the fly", you may choose to set a fixed width, say, "3cm", or whatever strikes your fancy.
- Instead of using a `\begin{turn} ... \end{turn}` wrapper, use a `\rotatebox{90}{...}` directive.
- Since the table features 5 data columns and hence 5 rotated header cells, it's useful to create a dedicated macro -- called `\mybox` below, but you're obviously free to choose a different name -- to manage the `\rotatebox` and `\parbox` chores.
- Since there's no need for (horizontal) line breaking in the 5 data columns, I suggest you replace the `p` column type with the `w` column type. (The `w` column type is provided by the `array` package.) By the way, a width of 1.5cm for the data columns seems excessive; in the code below, I set their widths to 0.75cm.
- Last but not least, do please give the table a more open "look" by omitting all vertical lines and using fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{array}     % for 'w' column type and '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{W}{>{$}w{c}{0.75cm}<{$}} % '1.5cm' seems excessive
\usepackage{graphicx}  % \rotatebox macro
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}  % \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule, \cmidrule
\usepackage{calc}      % \widthof macro
%% handy shortcut macro:
\newcommand\mybox[1]{\rotatebox{90}{%
    \parbox{\widthof{And so forth\ }}{\raggedright #1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!tbh]
\centering % <-- important

\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\em}l *{5}{W} @{}} 
\toprule 
   \textbf{\textup{Strategy}}
 & \multicolumn{5}{c@{}}{\textbf{Requirements}} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-6} 
 & \mybox{First requirement} 
 & \mybox{Second requirement} 
 & \mybox{And so on} 
 & \mybox{And so forth} 
 & \mybox{And so fifth} \\ 
\midrule 
Bla         & + & - & - & - & + \\  
Bla bla     & - & - & + & - & + \\ 
Bla bla bla & - & + & + & - & - \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}

\caption{\textbf{This is a table.} It shows things.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `nicematrix` (≥ 6.22 of 2023-08-14) and `booktabs` (and in the spirit of `booktabs`):

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{nicematrix}    
\usepackage{booktabs}  

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!tbh]
\centering 

\begin{NiceTabular}{@{} >{\itshape}l *{5}{w{c}{0.75cm}} @{}} 
  \toprule 
  \RowStyle[bold]{\upshape}
     Strategy
   & \Block{1-5}{Requirements} \\ 
  \cmidrule(l){2-6} 
  \RowStyle{\rotate}
   & \Block{}{First\\ requirement} 
   & \Block{}{Second\\ requirement} 
   & And so on
   & And so forth
   & And so fifth \\ 
  \midrule 
  Bla         & $+$ & $-$ & $-$ & $-$ & $+$ \\  
  Bla bla     & $-$ & $-$ & $+$ & $-$ & $+$ \\ 
  Bla bla bla & $-$ & $+$ & $+$ & $-$ & $-$ \\ 
  \bottomrule 
\end{NiceTabular}

\caption{\textbf{This is a table.} It shows things.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]